# Java inheritance/constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, constructor

If I was using a class called "Dog" and it extends a class called "Animal" is there a way to have the constructor use a parameter that takes an Animal object and then would require me not to use the super keyword to store the information required of an Animal object? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you want to make a copy of the original `Animal`. This is because `Dog` is an `Animal`, you can't pass in another `Animal` and make that the "parent" of your new object.

The way you should do this is to create a copy constructor in your parent class (Animal) that takes in the same type of object.

```
public Animal(Animal other) {
    this.field1 = other.field1;
    this.field2 = other.field2;
    ...
}
```

Then in your `Dog` class, you can do:

```
public Dog(Dog other) {
    super(other);
    this.breed = other.breed;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Glad I helped! If this was the answer, feel free to mark it as it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically, no.

Now `Animal` itself may have a (user-created) "copy constructor" style constructor that takes an `Animal` instance and from which it copies the fields, and you could pass the `Animal` object to this constructor to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> If I was using a class called "Dog"

```
class Dog {
}
```

> and it extends a class called "Animal"

```
class Animal {
}
class Dog extends Animal {
}
```

> is there a way to have the constructor

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    Dog() {
    }
}
```

> use a parameter that takes an Animal object

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    Dog(Animal otherAnimal) {
    }
}
```

> and then would require me not to use the `super` keyword

↑↑↑↑ No use of `super` keyword in above code ↑↑↑↑

> to store the information required of an Animal object?

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    Animal otherAnimal;
    Dog(Animal otherAnimal) {
        this.otherAnimal = otherAnimal;
    }
}
```

Information stored, and still no use of `super` keyword.

Comment: @Cresyls This fully answers your question, whose fault is that it's not what you meant?

Comment: @Oleg I know it's my fault for not explaining it correctly, it might technically answer my question, but it didn't at the same time

Comment: @Cresyls Unfortunately ACVM correctly guessed what you meant and gave a helpful answer to a question that should've been closed as 'unclear what you're asking' so I don't know if you learned anything from it.